# Updating a users email address in MailChimp API V3

Tags: mailchimp

I am running the following code (I've hidden ID's) to update a subscriber's email address in a MailChimp list:

```
$mailchimp->patch('lists/1234567/members/' . md5('test@test.com'), [
    'email_address' => 'new-email@newtest.com',
    'status' => 'subscribed',
    'merge_fields' => array(
        'FNAME' => 'Ben',
        'LNAME' => 'Sinclair',
    ),
]);
```

It does not seem to work. I do not receive any errors, it just does nothing.

How do you update an email address in a MailChimp list using API V3?

Comment: It seems that you can't, it's not listed as a parameter in the docs: http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/members/#edit-patch_lists_list_id_members_subscriber_hash. Which makes sense, as it would change the hash of that member.

Comment: @jonrsharpe You're probably right. You could do it in V2 but it seems I'll just have to change the way I do things for V3. I know, should have migrated to V2 a long time ago :P

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/members/#edit-patch_lists_list_id_members_subscriber_hash

Currently, the email address is a parameter (read only = false) in the PUT method (.../3.0/lists/{listId}/members/{md5}) that allows to change the email address of the subscriber.

I'm sending the new email in the body and MERGE0 (EMAIL) tag but using the md5 from the previous email. It is changing the email correctly.

Comment: I do not understood your answer. Can you please give any example

Comment: It should be something like: 
$mailchimp->patch('lists/1234567/members/' . md5('test@test.com'), [
    'email_address' => 'new-email@newtest.com',
    'status' => 'subscribed',
    'merge_fields' => array(
        'FNAME' => 'Ben',
        'LNAME' => 'Sinclair',
        'MERGE0' => 'new-email@newtest.com'
    ),
]);

Answer (score 1):

You can change the email address when you make the request

> **PUT** https://usx.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/{list_id}/members/{subscriber_hash}

and the body was this:

```
{"email_address": "new@email.com"}

$List = 123456;
$subscriber_hash = md5("old@email.com")
$data = array('email_address' => "new@email.com" );
$result = $mailchimp->put("lists/$List/members/$subscriber_hash", $data);
```